# Display Unicode data in TwwDBGrid

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7

I have built a project with Delphi 7 which retrieves data from SQL2000 DataBase. The columns in each table of the database that are intented to store strings have been set to nstring datatype. In my project I use the Delphi's ADO components to bring the data from the database (AdoConnection, AdoQuery, AdoDataset etc...) and TwwDBGrid to display them.

Now if I open a table from the sql server management studio I can view the Unicode data as it is. However, when I display them through one of my TwwDBGrids of my project it seems that the InfoPower's grid can not display the Unicode data. Instead it alters each Unicode character with the questionmark (?) character.

Is there any way to workaround this problem and see my Unicode data in InfoPower's TwwDBGrid ?

Comment: You are using a pre-Unicode version of Delphi. Why would you expect to be able to work with Unicode? You aren't using TnT Unicode components. It's time to get the right tool for the job. It's not Delphi 7. Get a modern version of Delphi.

Comment: Thank you David, I wish if only InfoPower 4000 had the capability to display Unicode characters. A small question.... if I change Infopower's components with TnT's will I have the same capabilities and functionality ?

Comment: I've no idea about the specific capabilities of these controls. Why not do some research based on your needs?